# Что такое "рельсы"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, терминология

Изучаю фрондэнд разработку. Спросили на соискательстве, работал ли я с рельсами. Я ответил "нет", но что это, типа, не сложно, а сам не знаю что это за термин. Не подскажите?

Comment: [Ruby_on_Rails -  фреймворк, написанный на языке программирования Ruby.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Это сленговое название фреймворка на языке Ruby - Ruby on Rails.

В настоящий момент в 99% случаев в контексте Web-программирования имеется именно Ruby on Rails - это довольно устойчивое сокращение как в русскоязычной среде, так и в англоязычной, где часто говорят просто Rails. Это флагманский фреймворк для Ruby, типа Spring на Java. Во многом благодаря ему, язык Ruby в принципе известен и входит в 10-ку популярных языков программирования.

Comment: кто их знает, что они имели ввиду?